# Прочитать содержимое JSON для последующей обработки средствами HTML5 и JavaScript без AJAX и сервера

Tags: javascript, json, html5

Я в web-программировании новичок. Столкнулась с такой проблемой. Есть файл JSON синтаксически правильный. В нем хранятся данные, часть из которых потом будет отображаться на странице  без перезагрузки (часть зависит от того ,какая ссылка нажата). Пользователь нажимает на ссылку, вызывается JavaSCript. Вот в самом скрипте и надо открыть файл JSON, обработать его содержимое и только потом вывести информацию на страницу. JSON, JS, как и Index.html хранятся на сервере, только в разных каталогах. Пользователь не должен иметь доступа к JSON, файл к нему не пересылается, ничего на сервер со стороны пользователя не загружается.
Указываю путь к JSON в виде fnm='/home/.../1.json' (переменная). Через new XMLHttpRequest() файл не открывается, fetch(fnm) выдает ошибку, а в new FileReader() я даже не знаю ,куда путь к файлу и имя файла прописывать. Помогите ,пожалуйста. Как извлечь содержимое файла в JS, записав его в одну троку (я ее потом распарсю) или сразу распарсить (чтобы не прописывать строку напрямую в скрипт ,копируя ручками из файла)?

```
 HTML <a id="Prosmotr_s" nohref onclick="Spisok_Rab ('/home/Site/ChgData/1.json')">  

JS Script во внешнем файле 

function Spisok_Rab(myURL) { //var myURL = 'file:////home/Site/ChgData/1.json" не сработала document.getElementById('Show_Spisok').innerHTML=myURL; Это я проверяла, что передается. В div выводится /home/Site/ChgData/1.json 
а дальше всё 
var Rq = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
Rq.onload = function() { 
var jsonData = JSON.parse(Rq.response); 
} 
Rq.open("GET", myURL, true); 
Rq.responseType = 'json'; 
Rq.send();
```

document.getElementById('Show_Spisok').innerHTML=jsonData;

```
}
```

И вот так тодже не работает:

```
fetch(myURL) 
 .then(  
    function(response) {  
      if (response.status !== 200) {  
        alert(response.status);  
        return;  
      }       
      (response => response.json())
      .then(function(data) {  
        alert(data); 
      });  
    }  
  )  
  .catch(function() {  
    alert(Ошибка'+myURL);  
  });
```

А если не JSON, а файл своего внутреннего формата? Ведь браузер открывает картинки, странички расположенные локально без сервера.
Смысл в том, чтоб обработка происходила на сервере. И чтоб пользователь не знал, что там обрабатывается, где хранится информация и в каком виде
Если в href прописать "/home/Site/ChgData/1.json", то браузер откроет его как страничку. Браузер локально тоже через ajaks работает?

После настройки Apach (большое всем, кто ответил! Отдельно ОГРОМНОЕ спасибо Sergei Kirjanov!)

```
     var jsonData;
   
var Rq = new XMLHttpRequest();
Rq.open("GET", "http://127.0.0.1/js/1.json", true);
Rq.responseType = 'text';
Rq.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if (Rq.readyState == 4 && Rq.status == "200") {
        jsonData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(jsonData);
       }
       else {
            alert('wait');
        }

 };
Rq.send(null);
```

Файл json открылся. Всё корректно считывается теперь. Ещё попробую вместо script тэг server использовать и попробую уже  с fetch разобраться. Думаю, что вместо файла json прикручу совсем свой формат, похожий на синтаксис json (сам файл не .json будет,  но чтоб его распарсить можно было)/

Теперь ещё проблема. С Лисичкой всё работает, а вот Хромой выдает ошибку Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1/js/1.json' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Политика CORS(((

Comment: так "Пользователь не должен иметь доступа к JSON", или пытаемся ему его загрузить?

Comment: где сервер, какой?

Comment: пишите "без AJAX", и сами его шлете...

Comment: Весь сайт сейчас у меня на компьютере. Локальный. Я использую JSON для типа простенькой БД. Настройки, ссылки и т.п. там храню.  Хочу на локалке всё отладить, чтоб уже потом работающий на хостинг перенести. Смысл в том, что JSON файл не должен быть виден пользователю, он не редактируется через сайт. Скрипт из него только читает. Потом я его ещё и hidden сделаю.

Comment: И данные из JSON файла пользователю напрямую не выводятся.

Comment: Я и не хочу пользователю этот файл передавать. Механизм такой : пользователь кликает кнопку или пункт меню. В функцию в скрипте передается только часть ссылки. Далее скрипт открывает JSON, составляет полную ссылку, при определенном условии еще считывает содержимое "полей" ( "title_rab", "adress_rab" формирует строку из этого. Строка идет в заголовок ссылки и отображается в виде надписи на кнопке, а уже после её нажатия подгрузится страница по сформированной ссылке.

Comment: Новая кнопка с новым заголовком и новой ссылкой - обычный div

Comment: Вам таки нужен AJAX и сервер. С помощью AJAX посылаете запрос, получаете данные, парсите. Сервер нужен для обработки вашего запроса - сервер подойдет любой.

Comment: Т.е. к серверу все равно нужен запрос, чтоб читать файлы на сервере, не передавая их клиенту? И значит, я не смогу посмотреть, работающий у меня сайт или нет, пока на хостинг не загружу? А как тогда на хостинге полностью блокировать доступ к домену со стороны пользователей , т.е.просмотр сайта (ну пока он не заработает)?

Comment: 1) Сервер можно запускать и у себя на компьютере. 2) код добавляйте не в комментарии, а в вопрос, и постарайтесь с сохранением форматирования. 3) если скрипт в браузере работает с json, значит и пользователь получит к нему доступ, просто нажав F12

Comment: Спасибо большое всем. Apach настроила

Comment: если js и json отдавать одним сервером -- CORS не должен вылезать -- `app.use(express.static('public'))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы хотите что-то не показывать пользователю -- вам нужно запускать свой **код на сервере**.

Если вы пишите только на js -- можно выбрать "Node.js".

Apache тоже можно, тогда на нем можно настроить или запуск cgi-скриптов, или передачу дальше `ProxyPass` на Node.js динамических запросов.
Этот вариант я не проверял.

Пример запроса на сервер:

```
fetch("/some.json")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))
```

Используйте "инструменты разработчика" в браузере, чтобы посмотреть `console.log`.

Код насервере можно в этом примере написать так, чтоб по запросу на "/some.json" он читал с диска секретный json-файл (недоступный для скачивания), что-то делал, и формировал несекретный json-ответ клиенту.

---

Достаточно простой вариант -- Node.js + expressjs:

https://expressjs.com/ru/starter/installing.html

https://expressjs.com/ru/starter/hello-world.html

https://expressjs.com/ru/starter/static-files.html

app.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/some.json', (req, res) => {
  res.send('{"ok":1}')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

public/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title> express </title>
</head>
<body>
HELLO
<script>

fetch("/some.json")
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => console.log(data))

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

`app.use(express.static('public'))` зазменяет апач: node.js будет сам раздавать статику из директирии 'public'.

Если апач нужен по другим причинам, можно поднять один сервер на 127.0.0.1, а другой на 127.0.0.2;

Если апач и нода должны работать совместно, можно настроить ProxyPass.

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Попробую с cgi скриптами

Comment: честно говоря, с cgi-скриптами это был экспромт на "Apach настроила"; я сам js, как cgi не запускал

Comment: буду проверять варианты

Comment: "express" достаточно просто вышло:
https://expressjs.com/ru/starter/installing.html

Comment: добавил про express

Comment: Спасибо большое! Буду разбираться с Node.js и с Вашим материалом и по ссылкам, и с примером кода

Comment: По node.js и ему подобых. Там предлагается после установки создать веб-сервер. А он с Апачем уживется?  И есть ли смысл? Если под Апачем его настроить на 127.0.0.1 ( скрипты и файлы json или своего формата), то ведь пользователю (браузеру извне)они не будут доступны?

Comment: добавил про 2 сервера

Comment: адреса 127.*.*.* напрямую доступны только локально

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я знаю про локалку 127.0.0.1 и про локальную сеть192.168...в IPv4.   Огромное спасибо еще раз!

Comment: Всегда рад. Принимайте ответ галочкой (на сайте около ответа), чтоб отметить, если вопрос решен. Создавайте новые вопросы по ходу  разработки.